# Python urllib2 Basic Auth Problem

Tags: python, authentication, urllib2

Update: based on Lee's comment I decided to condense my code to a really simple script and run it from the command line:

```
import urllib2
import sys

username = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]
url = sys.argv[3]
print("calling %s with %s:%s\n" % (url, username, password))

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, username, password)
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)))

req = urllib2.Request(url)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = f.read()
print(data)
```

Unfortunately it still won't generate the `Authorization` header (per Wireshark) :(

I'm having a problem sending basic AUTH over urllib2. I took a look at [this article](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml), and followed the example. My code:

```
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, "api.foursquare.com", username, password)
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)))

req = urllib2.Request("http://api.foursquare.com/v1/user")    
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = f.read()
```

I'm seeing the following on the Wire via wireshark:

```
GET /v1/user HTTP/1.1
Host: api.foursquare.com
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Python-urllib/2.5
```

You can see the Authorization is not sent, vs. when I send a request via curl: `curl -u user:password http://api.foursquare.com/v1/user`

```
GET /v1/user HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic =SNIP=
User-Agent: curl/7.19.4 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3
Host: api.foursquare.com
Accept: */*
```

For some reason my code seems to not send the authentication - anyone see what I'm missing?

thanks

-simon

Comment: I wonder if the problem is that the site is not returning a `'WWW-Authenticate'` header. You can check this by using `try: urllib2.urlopen(req) except urllib2.HTTPError, e: print e.headers` [See this SO post answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9698319/1020470).

Answer (score 202, accepted):

The problem could be that the Python libraries, per HTTP-Standard, first send an unauthenticated request, and then only if it's answered with a 401 retry, are the correct credentials sent. If the Foursquare servers don't do "totally standard authentication" then the libraries won't work.

Try using headers to do authentication:

```
import urllib2, base64

request = urllib2.Request("http://api.foursquare.com/v1/user")
base64string = base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password))
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Had the same problem as you and found the solution from this thread: http://forums.shopify.com/categories/9/posts/27662

Comment: HTTP Error 505: HTTP Version Not Supported  ;(

Comment: Works with paypal authentication (in order to receive access_token) as well. Thanks a lot, mate!

Comment: Similar problem here..In browser content of authorized page loaded and if i click cancel button i can see password page content's

Answer (score 5):

(copy-paste/adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24048772/1733117).

First you can subclass `urllib2.BaseHandler` or `urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler`, and implement `http_request` so that each request has the appropriate `Authorization` header.

```
import urllib2
import base64

class PreemptiveBasicAuthHandler(urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler):
    '''Preemptive basic auth.

    Instead of waiting for a 403 to then retry with the credentials,
    send the credentials if the url is handled by the password manager.
    Note: please use realm=None when calling add_password.'''
    def http_request(self, req):
        url = req.get_full_url()
        realm = None
        # this is very similar to the code from retry_http_basic_auth()
        # but returns a request object.
        user, pw = self.passwd.find_user_password(realm, url)
        if pw:
            raw = "%s:%s" % (user, pw)
            auth = 'Basic %s' % base64.b64encode(raw).strip()
            req.add_unredirected_header(self.auth_header, auth)
        return req

    https_request = http_request
```

Then if you are lazy like me, install the handler globally

```
api_url = "http://api.foursquare.com/"
api_username = "johndoe"
api_password = "some-cryptic-value"

auth_handler = PreemptiveBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(
    realm=None, # default realm.
    uri=api_url,
    user=api_username,
    passwd=api_password)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I'm using to deal with a similar problem I encountered while trying to access MailChimp's API. This does the same thing, just formatted nicer.

```
import urllib2
import base64

chimpConfig = {
    "headers" : {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic " + base64.encodestring("hayden:MYSECRETAPIKEY").replace('\n', '')
    },
    "url": 'https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/'}

#perform authentication
datas = None
request = urllib2.Request(chimpConfig["url"], datas, chimpConfig["headers"])
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Answer (score 4):

The second parameter must be a URI, not a domain name. i.e.

```
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, "http://api.foursquare.com/", username, password)
```

Comment: Thanks - I should have mentioned I tried that in a number of different combinations `http://api.foursquare.com`, `api.foursquare.com`, `http://api.foursquare.com/v1/`, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: I just tried this against a local server here that requires basic auth and with the URL in the add_password it worked fine. I would therefore suggest that something else is afoot.

Comment: This will only work if the http response contains code 401 Unauthorized **_and_** the header `'WWW-Authenticate'`; see [this SO post answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9698319/1020470).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the current solution is to use my package [urllib2_prior_auth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urllib2_prior_auth/) which solves this pretty nicely (I work on [inclusion](http://bugs.python.org/issue19494) to the standard lib.

Comment: Wil it allow to open urls like `urllib2.urlopen('http://USER:PASS@example.com/path/')`

Comment: This is another problem. Are you certain this doesn't work with the standard ``urllib2``?