# Python code like curl

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, pycurl

in curl i do this:

```
curl -u email:password http://api.foursquare.com/v1/venue.json?vid=2393749
```

How i can do this same thing in python?

Comment: See [Python urllib2 Basic Auth Problem
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407126/python-urllib2-basic-auth-problem), which is about using Basic Auth with Foursquare on Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The problem could be that the Python libraries, per HTTP-Standard, first send an unauthenticated request, and then only if it's answered with a 401 retry, are the correct credentials sent. If the Foursquare servers don't do "totally standard authentication" then the libraries won't work.

Try using headers to do authentication:"

taked from [Python urllib2 Basic Auth Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407126/python-urllib2-basic-auth-problem)

```
import urllib2
import base64

req = urllib2.Request('http://api.foursquare.com/v1/venue.json?vid=%s' % self.venue_id)
req.add_header('Authorization: Basic ',base64.b64encode('email:password'))
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's the equivalent in [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/):

```
import pycurl
from StringIO import StringIO

response_buffer = StringIO()
curl = pycurl.Curl()

curl.setopt(curl.URL, "http://api.foursquare.com/v1/venue.json?vid=2393749")

curl.setopt(curl.USERPWD, '%s:%s' % ('youruser', 'yourpassword'))

curl.setopt(curl.WRITEFUNCTION, response_buffer.write)

curl.perform()
curl.close()

response_value = response_buffer.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm more comfortable running the command line curl through subprocess.  This avoids all of the potential version matching headaches of python, pycurl, and libcurl.  The observation that pycurl hasn't been touched in 2 years, and is only listed as suppported through Python 2.5, made me wary. 
-- John

```
   import subprocess

   def curl(*args):
        curl_path = '/usr/bin/curl'
        curl_list = [curl_path]
        for arg in args:
            curl_list.append(arg)
        curl_result = subprocess.Popen(
                     curl_list,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        return curl_result

    answer = curl('-u', 'email:password', 'http://api.foursquare.com/v1/venue.json?vid=2393749')
```

Answer (score 1):

if use human_curl you can write some code

import human_curl as hurl

```
r = hurl.get('http://api.foursquare.com/v1/venue.json?vid=2393749', auth=('email','password'))
```

Json data in r.content

Answer (score 0):

Use pycurl

- http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/

There is a discussion on SO for tutorials

- [What good tutorials exist for learning pycURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997066/what-good-tutorials-exist-for-learning-pycurl)

A typical example:

```
import sys
import pycurl

class ContentCallback:
        def __init__(self):
                self.contents = ''

        def content_callback(self, buf):
                self.contents = self.contents + buf

t = ContentCallback()
curlObj = pycurl.Curl()
curlObj.setopt(curlObj.URL, 'http://www.google.com')
curlObj.setopt(curlObj.WRITEFUNCTION, t.content_callback)
curlObj.perform()
curlObj.close()
print t.contents
```

Comment: You can use `pycurl`, but it's not required.  It's quite possible to use the standard library.  See the question I linked above.