# does urllib2 support preemptive authentication authentication?

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I am trying access a REST API.

I can get it working in Curl/REST Client (the UI tool), with preemptive authentication enabled.

But, using urllib2, it doesn't seem to support this by default and I can't find a way to turn it on.

Thanks :)

Comment: Give us more details about what you need, what you've tried and how the UI tool works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple Preemptive HTTP basic auth handler, based on the code from `urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler`.  It can be used in the exact same manner, except an `Authorization` header will be added to *every* request with a matching URL.  Note that this handler should be used with a `HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm`.  That's because there is no realm coming back in a `WWW-Authenticate` challenge since you're being preemptive.

```
class PreemptiveBasicAuthHandler(urllib2.BaseHandler):

        def __init__(self, password_mgr=None):
                if password_mgr is None:
                        password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
                self.passwd = password_mgr
                self.add_password = self.passwd.add_password

        def http_request(self,req):
                uri = req.get_full_url()
                user, pw = self.passwd.find_user_password(None,uri)
                #logging.debug('ADDING REQUEST HEADER for uri (%s): %s:%s',uri,user,pw)
                if pw is None: return req

                raw = "%s:%s" % (user, pw)
                auth = 'Basic %s' % base64.b64encode(raw).strip()
                req.add_unredirected_header('Authorization', auth)
                return req
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate you take time to answer this question with a good explanation.

Answer (score 4):

similar to @thom-nichols's answer; but subclassing `HTTPBasicAuthHandler` also handling HTTPS requests.

```
import urllib2
import base64

class PreemptiveBasicAuthHandler(urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler):
    '''Preemptive basic auth.

    Instead of waiting for a 403 to then retry with the credentials,
    send the credentials if the url is handled by the password manager.
    Note: please use realm=None when calling add_password.'''
    def http_request(self, req):
        url = req.get_full_url()
        realm = None
        # this is very similar to the code from retry_http_basic_auth()
        # but returns a request object.
        user, pw = self.passwd.find_user_password(realm, url)
        if pw:
            raw = "%s:%s" % (user, pw)
            auth = 'Basic %s' % base64.b64encode(raw).strip()
            req.add_unredirected_header(self.auth_header, auth)
        return req

    https_request = http_request
```

here is an example for dealing with a jenkins server which does not send you `401` http errors (retry with auth). I'm using `urllib2.install_opener` to make things easy.

```
jenkins_url = "https://jenkins.example.com"
username = "johndoe"
api_token = "some-cryptic-value"

auth_handler = PreemptiveBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(
    realm=None, # default realm.
    uri=jenkins_url,
    user=username,
    passwd=api_token)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of authentication is required, you can send the Authorization headers manually by adding them to your request before you send out a body.