# Fetching a URL from a basic-auth protected Jenkins server with urllib2

Tags: python, http, authentication, jenkins, urllib2

I'm trying to fetch a URL from a Jekins server. Until somewhat recently I was able to use the pattern described on this page ([HOWTO Fetch Internet Resources Using urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html)) to create a password-manager that correctly responded to BasicAuth challenges with the user-name & password. All was fine until the Jenkins team [changed their security model](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients), and that code no longer worked.

```
# DOES NOT WORK!
import urllib2
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
top_level_url = "http://localhost:8080"

password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, 'sal', 'foobar')
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)

a_url = 'http://localhost:8080/job/foo/4/api/python'
print opener.open(a_url).read()
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sal/workspace/jenkinsapi/src/examples/password.py", line 11, in <module>
    print opener.open(a_url).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

The problem appears to be that Jenkins returns not with the expected 401 code, but a 403 which urllib2 interprets as an end of conversation. It never actually sends the password. After some surfing around github found another developer's solution which works...

```
# WORKS... SORTA
def auth_headers(username, password):
   return 'Basic ' + base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password))[:-1]

auth = auth_headers('sal', 'foobar')
top_level_url = "http://localhost:8080"
a_url = 'http://localhost:8080/job/foo/4/api/python'
req = urllib2.Request(a_url)
req.add_header('Authorization', auth)
print urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

But that seems rather unsatisfying. It's not bothering to check whether the domain is relevant to the username and password... it's just sending my login details regardless!

Can anybody suggest a way to make the original script work? I'd like to use a urllib2 password manager in such a way that I can login to Jenkins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this gist as well: https://gist.github.com/dnozay/194d816aa6517dc67ca1

Jenkins does not return `401 - retry` HTTP error code when you need to access a page that needs authentication; instead it returns `403 - forbidden`. In the wiki, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients, it shows that using the command-line tool `wget` you need to use `wget --auth-no-challenge` which is exactly because of that behavior.

### Retrying with basic auth when you get a `403 - forbidden`:

let's say you defined:

```
jenkins_url = "https://jenkins.example.com"
username = "johndoe@example.com"
api_token = "my-api-token"
```

You can subclass a `urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler` to handle `403` HTTP responses.

```
import urllib2

class HTTPBasic403AuthHandler(urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler):
    # retry with basic auth when facing a 403 forbidden
    def http_error_403(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        host = req.get_host()
        realm = None
        return self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
```

Then it is a matter of using that handler, e.g. you can install it so it works for all `urllib2.urlopen` calls:

```
def install_auth_opener():
    '''install the authentication handler.

    This handles non-standard behavior where the server responds with
    403 forbidden, instead of 401 retry. Which means it does not give you the
    chance to provide your credentials.'''
    auth_handler = HTTPBasic403AuthHandler()
    auth_handler.add_password(
        realm=None,
        uri=jenkins_url,
        user=username,
        passwd=api_token)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
    # install it for all urllib2.urlopen calls
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

and here is a simple test to see if it works okay.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # test
    install_auth_opener()
    page = "%s/me/api/python" % jenkins_url
    try:
        result = urllib2.urlopen(page)
        assert result.code == 200
        print "ok"
    except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
        assert err.code != 401, 'BAD CREDENTIALS!'
        raise err
```

### Using pre-emptive authentication.

There is a good example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513913/1733117.
Rather than retrying when you get a `403 forbidden` you would send the `Authorization` header when the url matches.

```
class PreemptiveBasicAuthHandler(urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler):
    '''Preemptive basic auth.

    Instead of waiting for a 403 to then retry with the credentials,
    send the credentials if the url is handled by the password manager.
    Note: please use realm=None when calling add_password.'''
    def http_request(self, req):
        url = req.get_full_url()
        realm = None
        # this is very similar to the code from retry_http_basic_auth()
        # but returns a request object.
        user, pw = self.passwd.find_user_password(realm, url)
        if pw:
            raw = "%s:%s" % (user, pw)
            auth = 'Basic %s' % base64.b64encode(raw).strip()
            req.add_unredirected_header(self.auth_header, auth)
        return req

    https_request = http_request
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than defining your own handler and installing it globally or using it for individual requests, it's a lot easier to just add the header to the request:

```
auth_header = 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % (USERNAME,
                                                      API_KEY)).strip()
headers = {'Authorization': auth_header}

request = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(data), headers)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: Even better, perhaps, is to add the `Authorization`-header once using the `opener.addheaders`. Then the opener can be reused for multitude of the requests without recreating the header every time. But the `.strip()` part is essential -- `b64encode()` seems to add `\n`, which, unless stripped, causes `httplib.py` to reject the header...