# Basic Auth urllib2 with HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm and POST data

Tags: python, urllib2, basic-authentication, unauthorized, http-error

I have this cURL call that works perfectly:

```
curl -H 'X-Requested-With: SO demo' -d 'parameter=value' https://username:password@api.domain.com/api/work/
```

My conversion does not work.

```
import urllib2
# Create a password manager.
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
# Add the username and password.
top_level_url = 'https://api.server.com'
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, 'username', 'password')
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
# Create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance).
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
# Install the opener so all calls to urllib2.urlopen use our opener.
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
# Create request.
headers = {'X-Requested-With':'SO demo.'}
uri = 'https://api.domain.com/api/work/'
data='parameter=value'
req = urllib2.Request(uri,data,headers)
# Make request to fetch url.
result = urllib2.urlopen(req)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Here's what I don't get.  The same server has a separate API which similar code does work on, where the only thing that has changed is the parameter and uri.  Note the cURL call works on both API calls.

Second API cURL call (that works):

```
curl -H 'X-Requested-With: SO demo' -d 'parameter=value' https://username:password@api.domain.com/api2/call.php
```

Equivalent code that works below:

```
import urllib2
# Create a password manager.
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
# Add the username and password.
top_level_url = 'https://api.server.com'
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, 'username', 'password')
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
# Create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance).
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
# Install the opener.
# Now all calls to urllib2.urlopen use our opener.
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
# Create request.
headers = {'X-Requested-With':'SO demo.'}
uri = 'https://api.server.com/api2/call.php'
data='parameter=value'
req = urllib2.Request(uri,data,headers)
# Make request to fetch url.
result = urllib2.urlopen(req)
# Read results.
result.read()
```

Why does urllib2 work when the uri ends with a '.php', but **not work** when the uri ends with a '/'?

Answer (score 2):

In the first request you are setting:

```
uri = 'https://api.domain.com/api/work/'
```

But if you were to do it the same as the second run, you probably meant to write it as:

```
uri = 'https://api.server.com/api/work/'
```

Comment: The second Python run was a comparison to the second curl run against the same uri.

Comment: I guess I'm confused then why sometimes you're sometimes calling api.domain.com and sometimes calling api.server.com.

Comment: The server has two API versions with different content for each version.

Answer (score 1):

From [Python urllib2 Basic Auth Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407126/python-urllib2-basic-auth-problem)

> The problem [is] that the Python libraries, per HTTP-Standard, first send an unauthenticated request, and then only if it's answered with a 401 retry, are the correct credentials sent. If the ... servers don't do "totally standard authentication" then the libraries won't work.

This particular API does not respond with a 401 retry on the first attempt, it responds with an XML response containing the message that credentials were not sent.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495279

Comment: Thanks Kev.  It turns out the solution was the same but I was only seeing different symptoms of the problem.  Should it still be a dup?