# Trouble with simple https authentication with urllib2 (to get PayPal OAUTH bearer token)

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, paypal, urllib2

I'm at the first stage of integrating our web app with PayPal's express checkout api. For me to place a purchase, I have to get a Bearer token of course using our client id and our client secret.

I use the following curl command to successfully get that token:

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
-u "ourID:ourSecret" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Now I am trying to achieve the same results in python using urllib2. I've arrived at the following code, which produces a 401 HTTP Unauthorized exception.

```
    import urllib
    import urllib2

    url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"

    PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID = "ourID"
    PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET = "ourSecret"

    passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    passman.add_password(None, url, PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID, PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET)
    authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    req = urllib2.Request( url=url,
      headers={
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Accept-Language": "en_US",
            },
      data =urllib.urlencode({
            "grant_type":"client_credentials",
            }),)

    result = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    print result
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong above? Many thanks for any insights

Comment: Finally gave in and used the sdk PayPal recommends (https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python) to get the token... that seems to work. But would still like to know what I'm doing wrong above if anyone has a clue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same problem here.  Based on [Get access token from Paypal in Python - Using urllib2 or requests library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476540) working python code is:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import base64
token_url = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token'
client_id = '.....'
client_secret = '....'

credentials = "%s:%s" % (client_id, client_secret)
encode_credential = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8').replace("\n", "")

header_params = {
    "Authorization": ("Basic %s" % encode_credential),
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}
param = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
}
data = urllib.urlencode(param)

request = urllib2.Request(token_url, data, header_params)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request).open()
print response
```

The reason, I believe, is explained at [Python urllib2 Basic Auth Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407126)

> Python libraries, per HTTP-Standard, first send an unauthenticated request, and then only if it's answered with a 401 retry, are the correct credentials sent. If the servers don't do "totally standard authentication" then the libraries won't work.