# Get access token from Paypal in Python - Using urllib2 or requests library

Tags: python, curl, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

#### cURL

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "client_id:client_secret" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Parameters:
`-u` take `client_id`:`client_secret`

Here I pass my `client_id` and `client_secret`, It's worked properly in cURL.

I am trying to same things implement on Python

#### Python

```
import urllib2
import base64
token_url = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token'
client_id = '.....'
client_secret = '....'

credentials = "%s:%s" % (client_id, client_secret)
encode_credential = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8').replace("\n", "")

header_params = {
    "Authorization": ("Basic %s" % encode_credential),
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}
param = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
}

request = urllib2.Request(token_url, param, header_params)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print "Response______", response
```

Traceback:

> result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
>
> ```
>  HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
> ```

Can you inform me whats wrong with my python code?

Answer (score 12):

Late answer, but as of 2021, I use the following python code to generate a new bearer token:

If you haven't done so, [create a new live app on developer.paypal.com](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create?env=live)
You'll receive a `Client ID` and a `Secret`, which you'll use to generate the Bearer Token.

[image]

Python Code:

```
import requests

d = {"grant_type" : "client_credentials"}
h = {"Accept": "application/json", "Accept-Language": "en_US"}

cid = "ASOGsGWr7yxepDuthbkKL-WoGNVAS7O0XlZ2ejcWsBA8ZXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
secret = "EJTKAFEYfN9IaVHc4Y-MECzgBivt2MfW6rcyfbVky0T07yRwuuTdXOczuCoEIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

r = requests.post('https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', auth=(cid, secret), headers=h, data=d).json()
access_token = r['access_token']
```

Sources:

1. https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/
2. https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-get-an-access-token-ts2128

Comment: It seems like the links are outdated.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Links are working fine fine, but paypal has the (bad) habit of changing   help urls based on user location/language, causing problems like the one you're facing.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using requests:

```
import requests
import base64

client_id = ""
client_secret = ""

credentials = "%s:%s" % (client_id, client_secret)
encode_credential = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8').replace("\n", "")

headers = {
    "Authorization": ("Basic %s" % encode_credential),
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
}

param = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
}

url = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token'

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=param)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: may I know why are you suggest `requests.post` instead of `urllib2.open` ?

Comment: @S͢kyD͢ream because it is the best HTTP library for Python, you can do a lot more, with less code/libraries than with the standard libs

Answer (score 0):

It needs URL encoding:

```
param = {
  'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
}

data = urllib.urlencode(param)
request = urllib2.Request(token_url, data, header_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer that worked for me with python 3.7. I needed to apply a `base64` encoding to my auth credentials:

```
import base64
import requests
from backend.config import Config


def get_paypal_access_token(client_id=Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID, secret=Config.PAYPAL_SECRET):
    url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"
    payload = 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    encoded_auth = base64.b64encode((Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID + ':' + Config.PAYPAL_SECRET).encode())
    headers = {
      'Authorization': f'Basic {encoded_auth.decode()}',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    r = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    assert r.status_code == 200
    return r.json()["access_token"]
```

I handle my client ID and secret from PayPal via a `Config` file, but hopefully it's straightforward how you would swap these out with your own credentials once you've registered your app.