# ./xx.py: line 1: import: command not found

Tags: python

I am trying to use the code at [Python urllib2 Basic Auth Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407126) to download content from a URL which requires authentication.

I have this code:

```
import urllib2, base64

request = urllib2.Request("http://api.foursquare.com/v1/user")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

But I get errors like:

```
./xx.py: line 1: import: command not found
./xx.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./xx.py: line 3: `request = urllib2.Request("http://api.foursquare.com/v1/user")'
```

What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

---

<sub>See also: [How do I make a python script executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494758) .</sub>

Comment: If import is not found then it is not related to authentication.  Can you try to run python and then enter each command one by one?

Comment: to avoid the `.replace()` call, use `base64.b64encode()` instead of `encodestring()`

Comment: You either need 1.) The shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` on the first line along with executable flag on the script file to be able to run the script with `./xx.py` OR 2.) you have to run the script with the `python xx.py` command. In the second case you don't need the shebang and the executable flag.

Comment: @pasztorpisti ...that said, if the goal is to define a command, the shebang and +x flag are the Right Approach (and the script probably shouldn't have a `.py` extension at all; see https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful for more discussion on that point).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sure, the `.py` extension on linux isn't needed. This  is basically true for all interpreted script files that have shebang + exec flag.

Comment: @pasztorpisti ...not just not needed, but actively harmful, as it means you can't reimplement in a different language without either needing to modify all callers or keeping it there with a now-misleading extension. And also, as we put it to people in #bash, "do you run `ls.elf`?"

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point. You can still reimplement it in a different language - it just looks ridiculous to have a bash script in a file with `.py` extension and its confusing at the same time. :-)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: *Installed* scripts (that are in PATH) do not need the file extension on Unix. Otherwise `.py` extension may be useful e.g., to import the file as a Python module.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, indeed so. However, if you're building something which is intended to be both a library and a command, best practice in the Python world is to develop and install it as a library and have setuptools build an extensionless (or, on Windows, `.exe`) wrapper for you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: yes. It is what setuptools' entry_points option does by default.

Comment: ...we're in rather violent agreement here, aren't we? :)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It's not an issue related to authentication at the first step. Your `import` is not working. So, try writing this on first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

and for the time being run using

```
python xx.py
```

For you here is one explanation:

```
>>> abc = "Hei Buddy"
>>> print "%s" %abc
Hei Buddy
>>> 

>>> print "%s" %xyz

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    print "%s" %xyz
NameError: name 'xyz' is not defined
```

At first, I initialized abc variable and it works fine. On the otherhand, xyz doesn't work as it is not initialized!

Comment: When I runned my script with your command then it shows: `base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (abc, xyz)).replace('\n', '')
NameError: name 'abc' is not defined`

Comment: You are replacing %s with a variable called abc, so you need to initialize that first!

Comment: Because `abc` is probably not instantiated. Don't get ahead of yourself. Instantiate your variables ahead of using them.

Comment: I added one example in my answer. Have a look into that!

Comment: It's not necessary to **both** add the shebang and explicitly invoke an interpreter. As such, I'm not sure this really constitutes good advice.

Comment: Also, the discussion of the unrelated variable initialization issues distract from the on-topic response to the actual question. Better to ask the questioner to file a separate Q than to make something that's less useful to other people.

Comment: [you do not need shebang if you run it as `python xx.py`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22275721/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, that's true, but phrasing it the way you do here implies that it's better to explicitly pass the interpreter and not use a shebang. That's generally contrary to accepted best practices.

Comment: On my Windows machine I had to add `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead of `#!/usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 11):

Are you using a UNIX based OS such as Linux? If so, add a **[shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script)** line to the very top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Underneath which you would have the rest of the code (`xx.py` in your case) that you already have. Then run that same command at the terminal:

```
$ python xx.py
```

This should then work fine, as it is now interpreting this as Python code. However when running from the terminal this does not matter as `python` tells how to interpret it here. What it does allow you to do is execute it outside the terminal, i.e. executing it from a file browser.

Comment: I know, that's obvious. I was just making the question more applicable to new users that may stumble across this post with the same problem, thank you. That way, when they read my post they know that if they are using UNIX it will be applicable to them.

Comment: When I runned my script with your command then it shows: `base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (abc, xyz)).replace('\n', '')
NameError: name 'abc' is not defined`

Comment: @user2481422 That cannot be, as the line that it is saying is incorrect is not in the code that you have posted. Post the full code. But anyway, Python is saying that it cannot find a variable named `abc`. Try declaring it first with `abc = 'some_value'`. But this is a separate issue, so I won't discuss it here. If the problem persists, ask a different question. The issue that you have posted in the question is solved with my answer.

Comment: [you do not need the shebang if you run it as `python xx.py`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22275721/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, indeed, but it's better to use the shebang and **not** use the explicit interpreter -- that way you're delegating the choice of interpreter to the program's author, who knows better than anyone else what the right interpreter for that program is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: the point is that *even if there is no shebang* the script runs if you use `python xx.py` (`python` even accepts an empty file here).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, absolutely true, but not a truth we should be encouraging newbies to take account or advantage of in their work.

Answer (score 10):

When you see "import: command not found" on the very first import, it is caused by the parser not using the character encoding matching your py file.  Especially when you are not using ASCII encoding in your py file.

The way to get it right is to specify the correct encoding on top of your py file to match your file character encoding.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
```

Comment: this should be helpful since utf-8 is the most popular encoding nowadays, even on Python source code

Comment: The answer is wrong. The error message is from the shell -- no python interpreter is running in this case. [My answer explains why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22275721/4279)

Comment: This is a completely wrong explanation and only shows working code by accident. This problem would produce a completely different error, and in Python 3, UTF-8 is the default encoding, **not ASCII**. A coding declaration like the one shown would not help. What **does** solve the problem here is the **first** line, which is telling *the shell* that *the file is Python source code*. That has nothing to do with character encoding.

Answer (score 5):

If you run a script directly e.g., `./xx.py` and your script has no shebang such as `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the very top then your shell may execute it as a shell script. [POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01):

> If the execl() function fails due to an error equivalent to the
>   [ENOEXEC] error defined in the System Interfaces volume of
>   POSIX.1-2008, the shell shall execute a command equivalent to having a
>   shell invoked with the pathname resulting from the search as its first
>   operand, with any remaining arguments passed to the new shell, except
>   that the value of "$0" in the new shell may be set to the command
>   name. If the executable file is not a text file, the shell may bypass
>   this command execution. In this case, it shall write an error message,
>   and shall return an exit status of 126.

Note: you may get `ENOEXEC` if your text file has no shebang.

Without the shebang, you shell tries to run your Python script as a shell script that leads to the error: `import: command not found`.

Also, if you run your script as `python xx.py` then you do not need the shebang. You don't even need it to be executable (`+x`). Your script is interpreted by `python` in this case.

On Windows, shebang is not used unless [pylauncher is installed](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher). It is [included in Python 3.3+](http://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#launcher).

Comment: This is the best explanation of why and when the problem happens.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced the same problem and now I just found my solution to this issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os

os.system('meld "%s" "%s"' % (sys.argv[2], sys.argv[5]))
```

This is the code[1] for my case. When I tried this script I received error message like :

> import: command not found

I found people talks about the shebang. As you see there is the shebang in my python code above.
I tried these and those trials but didn't find a good solution.

I finally tried to type the shebang my self.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

and removed the copied one.

And my problem solved!!!

I copied the code from the internet[1].

And I guess there had been some unseeable(?) unseen special characters in the original copied shebang statement.

I use vim, sometimes I experience similar problems.. Especially when I copied some code snippet from the internet this kind of problems happen.. Web pages have some virus special characters!! I doubt. :-)

Journeyer

PS) I copied the code in Windows 7 - host OS - into the Windows clipboard and pasted it into my vim in Ubuntu - guest OS. VM is Oracle Virtual Machine.

[1] http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-meld-for-git-diffs-in-ubuntu-hardy

Answer (score 0):

It's about [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

```
#!usr/bin/python
```

This will tell which interpreter to wake up to run the code written in file.

Comment: This does not add anything that was not in previous answers, and also the code is wrong (it should use an absolute path).