# How to go from Request to Urllib2

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, urllib

I need to rewrite the following function using only the python standard library.

```
def request_release_info(self):
    req = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/releases/latest',
                       auth=('user', 'token'))
    content = req.json()
    return content
```

So I need to replace Requests by Urllib/Urllib2 but I'm unable to find a way to pass my username and my token in a similar way.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Are you on Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm on python 2.7.11

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2407126/

Comment: yes, I used the first answer's code and it didn't work :(

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you need to go from requests to urllib2?

Comment: I'm building a very small mac app with py2app and unfortunately when I add the requests package I have an error that can't be fixed easily so the easiest way that I found to avoid this issue is to use only the std lib

Comment: Try the most upvoted answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635113/python-urllib2-basic-http-authentication-and-tr-im

Comment: Thanks !! The second answer was the right one for my problem !

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib, json

result = urllib.urlopen('https://<My_Token>:x-oauth-basic@api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/releases/latest')
r = json.load(result.fp)

print r
result.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is example usage of your code, but don't forget about error processing.

```
from urllib import request
from urllib import error
from base64 import b64encode

def request_release_info(self):
    # build authorization
    user_and_pass = b64encode(b"username:password").decode("ascii")

    # first, we build request
    my_req = request.Request('https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/releases/latest')

    # then attach auth header
    my_req.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % user_and_pass)

    # and after that try to execute it
    try:
        content = request.urlopen(my_req)
    except error.HTTPError:
        content = "add error processing, example for wrong log/password"

    return content
```