# urllib2 not accepting credentials in URL

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, urllib2, httplib

The form-based login for a webpage can often by bypassed with the following URL structure:

```
https://myusername:mypassword@myserver.com
```

(note: I know there are security concerns here; that is beyond the scope of this question).

`urllib2` doesn't like this:

```
urllib2.urlopen('http://myusername:mypassword@myserver.com')
InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: 'mypassword@myserver.com'
```

I guess it is seeing the second as the start of the URL. I know that the `requests` library has no such problems. But for legacy reasons, I am stuck with using `urllib2`. Is it possible to get around this with `urllib2`?

Comment: [Relevant](http://bugs.python.org/issue944396)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2407126/172176

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4188709/1555990) should help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python urllib2, basic HTTP authentication, and tr.im](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635113/python-urllib2-basic-http-authentication-and-tr-im)