# Python 2.7 HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: python, python-2.7, basic-authentication

maybe someone can help me with this. I'm trying to get a data from a website using Python 2.7, using HTTP Basic Authentication.
The only instructions the website provides is this:

> In order for your web service client to authenticate using basic
> authentication, the first HTTPS request must include the
> "Authorization" header specifying the account credentials to
> authenticate with. The header for a such a request would look like
> this:
>
> ```
>   GET /polcs/trade.xml HTTP/1.0
>   Host: secure.pol.com
>   Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
> ```

I tried few things but neither of them works, for example:

```
import urllib2
import base64

b = base64.encodestring('USERNAME:PASSWORD').replace('\n', '')
conf = {'headers': {'GET': '/polcs/trade.xml HTTP/1.0', 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + b},
    'url': 'secure.pol.com'}
datas = None
request = urllib2.Request(conf['url'], datas, conf['headers'])
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

This one gives me HTTP Error 403:

```
url = 'https://secure.pol.com/polcs/data.xml'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
b = base64.encodestring('USERNAME:PASSWORD').replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic " + b)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Can someone please tell me where do I make a mistake trying to get that data?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you try `base64.b64encode('USERNAME:PASSWORD')` instead of `base64.encodestring('USERNAME:PASSWORD')` to match the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2955687/4636715

Comment: @vahdet Same result. 403 Error