# Error while accessing workdy RAAS report through python

Tags: python, python-requests, workday-api

I am trying to access the workday report through python. i am able to access this through browser with userid and passwd. But when i run through python i am getting the below error.

```
import os
import platform
import ssl
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
ssl_context.check_hostname = True
ssl_context.load_default_certs()

if platform.system().lower() == 'windows':
   import certifi
   print(os.path.relpath(certifi.where()))
   ssl_context.load_verify_locations(
    #cafile=os.path.relpath(certifi.where()),
    cafile="C:\\abc_Tools\\TDX_INT166\\Lib\\site-packages\\certifi\\workday.pem",
    capath=None,
    cadata=None)
   print(platform.system().lower())
url = 'https://wd5-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/customreport2/xxx/ISU_INT167/CR_- 
     _FIN_Report'
username = 'XXXXXXXXX'  # 10 digit ID
password = 'XXXXXXXXX'

values ={'username' : username, 'password':password}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8")
#cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()

https_handler = urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(context=ssl_context)

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(https_handler)
ret = opener.open(url, timeout=2)
print(ret)
```

I am getting the below error.

```
site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem
windows
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\SLU_Tools\TDX_INT166\Lib\Certificate_testing.py", line 38, in <module>
ret = opener.open(url, timeout=2)
File 
"C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", 
line 523, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File 
"C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", 
line 632, in http_response
response = self.parent.error(
File 
"C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", 
line 561, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File 
"C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", 
line 494, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File 
"C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", 
line 641, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

I tried other ways as well. But nothing worked. so far. Is this something doable?

Answer (score 0):

When calling a RAAS this way, you need to authenticate using Basic Auth. The username/password needs to be Base64 encoded and the result is added as an HTTP header. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2955687/25122) for an example.

Comment: raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='wd5-impl-services1.workday.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ccx/service/customreport2/slu/ISU_ActiveEmp/CR-Active_Emp_Info (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)')))

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up the authorizations using the `Basic Auth` type, and you will need to encode your username/password following the `Basic Auth` schemes -- converting the credentials to base64 first, then back to a string format and using it in the authorization string.

I used code similar to the snippet below in our web applications:

```
import requests, base64

url = '<Workday_RaaS_API_Endpoint>'
username = '<your_RaaS_user_username>'
password = '<your_RaaS_user_password>' # replace with the password here

auth = 'Basic %s' % base64.b64encode(bytes('%s:%s' % (username, password), 'utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
headers = { 'Authorization': auth }

res = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(res.json())
```