# retrieving a page that redirects to a login page within python

Tags: python, https, urllib2

I am having a rough time gathering the data from a website programatically.  I am attempting to utilize [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045886/https-log-in-with-urllib2/1045905#1045905) to log into the server, but it is not working since I think that this is the wrong type of login.

The site I am trying to access redirects to a login page when I attempt to download the data to parse the html.

This is the URL:

https://mtred.com/rewards.html

and heres the code:

```
# build opener with HTTPCookieProcessor
o = urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor() )
urllib2.install_opener( o )
# assuming the site expects 'user' and 'pass' as query params
p = urllib.urlencode( { 'UserLogin_username': 'mylogin', 'UserLogin_password': 'mypass' } )
# perform login with params
f = o.open( 'http://www.mtred.com/user/login.html',  p )
data = f.read()
f.close()
# second request should automatically pass back any
# cookies received during login... thanks to the HTTPCookieProcessor
f = o.open( 'https://www.mtred.com/rewards.html',p )
data = f.read()
print data
```

it kicks me to the login page again when I attempt to open rewards.  I am trying to pass the rewards to do some statistics automatically since this information isn't available via public API

Answer (score 1):

One issue that pops out is that you're passing in the `id` values of the form parameters for the login, not the `name` parameters. E.g., in the user name form field, you are specifying `UserLogin_username`, but the name of that field as expected by the server is `"UserLogin[username]"`

```
<label for="UserLogin_username" class="required">
username or email <span class="required">*</span></label>       
<input name="UserLogin[username]" id="UserLogin_username" type="text" />    </div>

<div class="row">
<label for="UserLogin_password" class="required">password <span class="required">*</span></label>   
<input name="UserLogin[password]" id="UserLogin_password" type="password" /> </div>
```

Since the server isn't getting back parameters that it knows about, the behavior you're seeing is not unexpected. (Not saying that there aren't **other** problems here; haven't looked.)

Answer (score 0):

you must inclue in ur post data the value named "YII_CSRF_TOKEN" that included in html form .
or use "[ClientForm](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/old/ClientForm/)" lib