# Accessing Video Data with Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ethernet

**Question**

How can I take a small sample of streamed frames, and manipulate them using Python? Are there any available libraries to use, or will I have to code the entire project alone?

**Tech Specs**

OS: Linux

Connection: CAT-5 Ethernet

Camera: [dlink DCS-930L](http://mydlink.dlink.com/products/DCS-930L)

**Introduction**

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966997/ethernet-packet-processing-with-python), but it was closed because of clarity issues.

I am re-posting with many more details, and if it is still not clear, feel free to edit or add comments.

**Background**

I have a dlink DCS-930L camera which is directly connected to my Linux computer with a direct [cat5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) connection. I assigned it to a static IP adress, and everything works great.

When I open a web-browser, and connect to this static IP address (e.g. log into 192.168.0.20), the camera just works correctly in real time.

I did this was to verify that my camera was working, and that I was able to establish the Ethernet connection correctly.

Now, what I need to  do some image processing on the video frames that I receive over the Ethernet from the camera.

I don't want to use the web-browser anymore as a means of display, and instead, I want to use Python to read the frames.

In other words, let's say that the camera produces 30 frames/second, and each frame has a certain size (e.g 1920x1080 pixels).

All I want to do is to start reading these frames in by Python. I don't mind if I am missing frames and if I am processing it slowly. Even if I am able to process one frame over a few seconds, I am still okay with that.

Since video is a collection of images (in this case 30 images per second), I want to be able to read these images using Python, and then be able to do whatever processing that I need to do on these images.

If I had these images saved on the computer, I would open these images with Python, and start to manipulate them. But, since in this case, the images are in fact being streamed, I just want to know how can I sample them (maybe one every few second), and do some manipulation using Python?

Please let me know if my question is still unclear, and I will try to clarify it as much as I can.

Thanks, 
--Rudy

Comment: Depends on what streaming formats does the camera support, I suppose

Comment: Which version of Python? Do you want us to write the code, or provide libraries?

Comment: I am not sure what version is running on the computer. I have to check. But is what I want to do a fairly complicated process? Is it even doable with Python? If you can point me in some direction I would appreciate it. For example what is involved in this process? Do I need to worry about the details of the protocols? For example, in the past I worked with an API written in C, to receive data over ethernet, and it was very complicated. But fortunately enough back then, the API tool care of all low level UDP protocols, and I didn't need to worry about that. What is the deal with Python?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.dlink.se%2FProducts%2Fdcs-products%2Fdcs-930l%2Fdocumentation%2FDCS-930L_A1_Manual_v1.00(W).pdf&ei=tBwkUengHITl0QHL4oGoBg&usg=AFQjCNHMShOHdxhZ25KC9alo7agsC5C0AA), the camera serves video through a java applet, so that is will bedifficult to access through python without understanding that server protocol.

However, it does have an option to push images to at ftp server (page 34), so if you install vsftpd on your linux box, you can tell the camera to push images there at maybe as high as 4 fps. There are instructions on setting up vsftpd on ubuntu [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-vsftpd-ftp-service-server/), other versions of linux will be similar (I seem to remember fedora needing slightly less setup, but that was years ago).

You will need to enable uploads with the line `write_enable=YES` in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`. There are various ways to handle the uploads, the simplest one would be to have it log in with your user account, it will then dump images in your home directory (or a path you specify in the camera config).

You should then be able to open the images normally, ie with PIL.

If you don't want to set up a fileserver, you can try grabbing data directly with urllib2, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045886/https-log-in-with-urllib2) page for how to handle the login. There is some chance by fooling around with fetching data you will be able to extract a video stream, but I think the ftp option will be a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed directions. I will try them all, and see where it takes me. By the way, out of curiosity, I read something about using OpenCV in conjunction with Python. (e.g. http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/75653). Any idea about using OpenCV. It looks like some who tried, didn't have much success in getting it up and running. But do you consider this as another avenue?

Comment: OpenCV looks like a slightly more convienent way of grabbing frames than doing it directly with urllib2, but it doesn't change the fact that you probably have to understand how the camera is serving images (and in this case probably communicate with a java applet). It is hard for me to know much more without being able to poke at an actual running instance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with exactly how the dlink DCS-30 works, but I have an earlier-generation model, the dlink DCS-20, and had the same objective, so maybe you can leverage my DCS-20 solution, or parts of it, to solve same for the DCS-30.

The key was just parsing the HTML provided by the built-in web browser access.

External modules requests, PIL, and BeautifulSoup simplify the solution.

Assuming your camera IP is 192.168.0.20, and that you've set up via the webadmin a user login to the camera of user1/pw1, here's the crux of the solution:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

import requests
from PIL import Image
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

DCS_IP = "192.168.0.20"
userauth = ('user1', 'pw1')

snapurl = "http://" + DCS_IP + "/top.htm"

r = requests.get(snapurl, auth=userauth)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

# There are several <img> tags in page, so use border=0 attribute of 
# objective <img> to distinguish it
imgtag = soup.find_all("img", attrs={'border':0})
imgsrc = BeautifulSoup(str(imgtag[0])).img['src']
imgurl = "http://" + DCS_IP + "/" + imgsrc

img = requests.get(imgurl, auth=userauth)
i = Image.open(StringIO(img.content))
i.save("snapshot.png")
```

Once you've retrieved the image (i), you can manipulate further with PIL, or, afterwards, use ffmpeg to, for example, stitch resulting image set into a time-lapse video.

HTH